# How to know when image is selected in Recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am using image picker inside recycler view using this code

adapter

```
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.tvAnimalType.text = items[position].name
    holder.image.setOnClickListener{


        requestPermissions(it.context as Activity , arrayOf(WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE),1)


        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
        intent.type = "image/*"
        (it.context as Activity).startActivityForResult(intent, 1)
        Log.i(uri.toString(),"hello")
    }

}
```

ParentActivity

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    Log.d("selectedImageUri()","hello")

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        1 -> {/*file front*/
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                val selectedImageUri = data.data as Uri
                val selectedImageBitmap: Bitmap =
                    MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, selectedImageUri)
                adapter!!.uri(selectedImageUri)
                Log.d(selectedImageUri.toString(),"hello")

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is how to know when image is selected by the user as the gallery activty runs in async.

Comment: Where in your code do you want to access the image selected?

Comment: I want to add image to imageview of recyclerview